# xml and html escaping special characters

Tags: php, html, xml, escaping, special-characters

i store my article in a xml file, so if i write into it special characters `"'` xml automatically escapes this characters and when i get(via PHP) the xml content i get something like `\"`. so if i write into xml `"hello dude"` my html will look like this `\"hello dude\"` 
how can i get the xml content like it was initially inserted(`"hello dude"`)? thanks

Answer (score 1):

You haven't specified how you are reading or outputting the data, but neither HTML nor XML use the `\` character to escape anything.

You might have [magic quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.php) turned on. I'd suggest turning it off, as it isn't very effective. You can hack around it with [stripslashes](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php).

Answer (score 1):

[`html_entity_decode()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) takes an html-encoded strings and removes escaping (e.g., `&lt;` into  `<`).

[`stripslashes()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.stripslashes.php) unescapes slashes (e.g. `\'` into `'`).